# How to select radio button and next page button in Selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I am new to Selenium and trying to set it up for a sort of interview process on my web application which includes selecting radio buttons (as in ‘I agree’ or ‘I disagree’) and manually typing values through the IDE. My first issue comes from the selection of radio buttons that do not reload the page – I played around with some of the commands, such as waitForElementPresent which passed the test, however, the actual page did not change or the button that needs to be clicked after was not clicked, and could not proceed in this interview process. Is there a command/way to accomplish this or do I have to do it through the WebDriver, which I am even more unfamiliar with?

Update: I have fixed the selecting radio buttons problem (using waitForElementPresent), however, I'm still having trouble changing pages through buttons - I tried changing the xpath but my buttons do not have names or ids, just public-keys which are not recognized.

```
xpath=(//button[@type='button' and @public-key='CWThisIsNotLegalAdvice'])
```

Any help is appreciated!

What I have so far (my problem is currently at button 4):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.citizenshipworks.org/" />
<title>interviewTest_1</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">interviewTest_1</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>clickAndWait</td>
 <td>id=getStarted</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[2]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
 <td>id=rbtnThisIsNotLegalAdviceTextIagree</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>css=label</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[4]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=txtMonth</td>
 <td>May</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=txtDay</td>
 <td>18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>type</td>
 <td>id=txtYear</td>
 <td>1980</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What selenium language binding are you using (e.g. Java, C#, python, etc.)?  And have you written the selenium code?  You should edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I am currently only using the IDE. Would the rest be necessary for such a task?

Comment: @orde I edited my question with the problem/xpath that is not working.